# CKFinder doesn't have permissions required

Tags: drupal, permissions, ckfinder

I have a drupal site with CKEditor as a WYSIWYG editor and would like to use 
CKFidner to upload pictures but after enbaling the permissions for the administrator, I still get an error like: "The file browser is disabled for security reasons. Please contact your system administrator and check the CKFinder configuration file" - Why would that be?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Uploading images through ckeditor is one way to have images in your content. By experience I suggest you to try the imagefield & the insert module. This way you can control from views the  uploaded images to your nodes and have photo/teaser displays easily, create galleries in nodes with more than 2 images or whatever you want, because your images will be saved in a structured way on your node.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
function CheckAuthentication()
{

    return false;
}
```

By default `CheckAuthentication()` it is disabled for security reason, because it would allow anyone to upload files to your server.

For testing purposes you can return `true` but the point is that you implement some logic to only authorize autenticated user.

```
function CheckAuthentication()
{
    //put some logic here

    return isset($_SESSION['IsAuthorized']) && $_SESSION['IsAuthorized'];
}
```